# Watchguard Web UI Authentication with Active Directory user

Tags: watchguard, firebox

Our WatchGuard firebox is configured to use active directory to authenticate VPN users. With Watchguard products, is it generally possible to use active directory to authenticate users that are attempting to configure the firewall itself, via the web UI?